# Google Analytics Tracker file in Android library module

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to split my Google Analytics code into a separate module (package com.abc) from my main app (package com.xyz). I am facing these issues :

1. Should I generate tracker for app module, or library module ?
2. Where should I put this tracker - app or library module ?
3. My goal is to have all Analytics creation and handling logic in the library module through some interfaces. I want to use this library for my other projects too; so I don't want to put tracker files in the library module itself. Is there a way I can initialize the tracker in the library module, but keep the XML file in app module  ?

What I have tried (and failed) :

1. I have generated tracker files for both com.abc and com.xyz
2. I have tried all permutations of both files in both modules; but the library module is unable to resolve R.xml.global_tracker. Being new to Google Analytics I don't know if I have to copy/paste any tracker file. Before I made the library module, R.xml.global_tracker was automatically resolved in the main module.

Comment: I'm also very interested in an answer to this. Have you come up with any solutions yet?

Comment: Also interested in a similar setup for iOS applications where there are multiple targets- each target using a different bundle ID(therefore needing a different google-services plist...?)

Comment: you don't need to make R.xml.global_tracker anymore. this is super easy to install GA to your project. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project just follow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue when implementing Google Analytics to the project with 2 modules (main app module and library module). There is a solution via Java Reflection how to get GA tracker in library module.

1. Generate tracker for your main app module.
2. Put tracker to your main app following to the [Google GA Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).
3. Add a dependency for Google Play Services to your library project: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'` This is necessary to use analytics classes in library module.

Finally, you will have GA configuration in your main app module. You can use it as described in guide:

```
// Obtain the shared Tracker instance in main module
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

For library module to get tracker from your custom Application class you can use reflection:

```
public Tracker getGATracker(Application application) {
    Tracker tracker = null;
    try {
        Method m = application.getClass().getMethod("getDefaultTracker", (Class<?>[]) null);
        Object result = null;
        if (m != null) {
            result = m.invoke(application, (Object[]) null);
            if (result != null) {
                tracker = (Tracker) result;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Can't get GA tracker: ", e);
    }

    return tracker;
}
```

Use method above with this snippet:

```
// Obtain the shared Tracker instance from main module
Tracker tracker = getGATracker(getApplication());
```

So you can use GA tracker in library module and have configuration in main module.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using R.xml.global_tracker.You can use this code in your Application class.

```
/**
 * @return tracker
 */
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

      // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker("Tracker code");
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1);
        mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        mTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

And use it in the activity/fragment like this:

```
    MyApplication application = (MyApplication ) context.getApplication();
    Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName(name);
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

This might resolve your problem, not tested for your case though.